# Importing non used SCSS files with VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I have an index in npm package that exports vue components:

```
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld/HelloWorld.vue'
import ByeWorld from './ByeWorld/ByeWorld.vue'

export {
    HelloWorld,
    ByeWorld
}
```

In the homepage project have a page with HelloWord import:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { HelloWorld } from 'test-project-f/src/components';

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

Inspecting page with F12 Tools. We can see vue injecting both scss instead of only HelloWord. There isn't references of ByeWorld in whole project

```
<style type="text/css">.hello[data-v-541c6422] {
  color: green;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">.bye[data-v-ef3e2c3c] {
  color: cadetblue;
}
</style>
```

Why? Anyone knows how to import only the necessary scss import?

I tried many ways:

- import all in index
- like a vue-cli bundle (vue-cli-service build --target lib --name
  myLib ./src/components/index.js)

HelloWorld:

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld'
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .hello {
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

ByeWorld:

```
<template>
    <div class="bye">
        <p>bye</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ByeWorld'
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .bye {
    color: cadetblue;
  }
</style>
```